# cards not coming in row direction in dashboard

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a Dashboard in which there is a section where I'm rendering cards i found the cards link on code pen the problem is my cards is not coming in row direction which is give a bad look in desktop view. I checked the CSS 3-4 times but couldn't find the anything which can help to make them in row direction. I'm providing both my code and the original cards code and mine code. help to to achieve  the row direction.
Thx in advance

**my code**

```
{% extends 'blood/adminbase.html' %} {% block content %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <style>
      #content main .head-title {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
        grid-gap: 16px;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
      }
      #content main .head-title .left h1 {
        font-size: 36px;
        font-weight: 600;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        color: var(--dark);
      }
      /* ======== */
      .ag-format-container {
        width: 1142px;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }

      .ag-courses_box {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-align: start;
        -ms-flex-align: start;
        align-items: flex-start;
        -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-direction: row!important;
        /* justify-content: space-between; */

        padding: 50px 0;
      }
      .ag-courses_item {
        -ms-flex-preferred-size: calc(33.33333% - 30px);
        flex-basis: calc(33.33333% - 30px);

        margin: 0 15px 30px;

        overflow: hidden;

        border-radius: 28px;
      }
      .ag-courses-item_link {
        display: block;
        padding: 30px 20px;
        background-color: #121212;

        overflow: hidden;

        position: relative;
      }
      .ag-courses-item_link:hover,
      .ag-courses-item_link:hover .ag-courses-item_date {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #fff;
      }
      .ag-courses-item_link:hover .ag-courses-item_bg {
        -webkit-transform: scale(10);
        -ms-transform: scale(10);
        transform: scale(10);
      }
      .ag-courses-item_title {
        min-height: 87px;
        margin: 0 0 25px;

        overflow: hidden;

        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 30px;
        color: #fff;

        z-index: 2;
        position: relative;
      }
      .ag-courses-item_date-box {
        font-size: 18px;
        color: #fff;

        z-index: 2;
        position: relative;
      }
      .ag-courses-item_date {
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #f9b234;

        -webkit-transition: color 0.5s ease;
        -o-transition: color 0.5s ease;
        transition: color 0.5s ease;
      }
      .ag-courses-item_bg {
        height: 128px;
        width: 128px;

        z-index: 1;
        position: absolute;
        top: -75px;
        right: -75px;

        border-radius: 50%;

        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
      }

      @media only screen and (max-width: 979px) {
        .ag-courses_item {
          -ms-flex-preferred-size: calc(50% - 30px);
          flex-basis: calc(50% - 30px);
        }
        .ag-courses-item_title {
          font-size: 24px;
        }
      }

      @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
        .ag-format-container {
          width: 96%;
        }
      }
      @media only screen and (max-width: 639px) {
        .ag-courses_item {
          -ms-flex-preferred-size: 100%;
          flex-basis: 100%;
        }
        .ag-courses-item_title {
          min-height: 72px;
          line-height: 1;

          font-size: 24px;
        }
        .ag-courses-item_link {
          padding: 22px 40px;
        }
        .ag-courses-item_date-box {
          font-size: 16px;
        }
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="head-title">
      <div class="left">
        <h1>Dashboard</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ============ -->
    <div class="ag-format-container">
        <!-- code injected here -->
    
    </div>
    <!-- ============ -->
    <script>
      const bloodTypes = [
        { type: "A+", unit: "{{A1.unit}}", color: "#3ecd5e" },
        { type: "B+", unit: "{{B1.unit}}", color: "#e44002" },
        { type: "O+", unit: "{{O1.unit}}", color: "#952aff" },
        { type: "AB+", unit: "{{AB1.unit}}", color: "#cd3e94" },
        { type: "A-", unit: "{{A2.unit}}", color: "#4c49ea" },
        { type: "B-", unit: "{{B2.unit}}", color: "#7D0552" },
        { type: "O-", unit: "{{O2.unit}}", color: "#5D6D7E" },
        { type: "AB-", unit: "{{AB2.unit}}", color: "#2ECC71" },
      ];

      const container = document.querySelector(".ag-format-container"); // assuming that you have a container element with a class of 'container'

      bloodTypes.map((bloodType) => {

        const ItemBodyBox = document.createElement("div");
        ItemBodyBox.classList.add("ag-courses_box");

        const ItemBody = document.createElement("div");
        ItemBody.classList.add("ag-courses_item");

        const itemLink = document.createElement("a");
        itemLink.classList.add("ag-courses-item_link");
        itemLink.href = "#";

        const itemBg = document.createElement("div");
        itemBg.classList.add("ag-courses-item_bg");
        itemBg.style.backgroundColor = bloodType.color;

        const itemTitle = document.createElement("div");
        itemTitle.classList.add("ag-courses-item_title");
        itemTitle.textContent = bloodType.type;

        const itemDateBox = document.createElement("div");
        itemDateBox.classList.add("ag-courses-item_date-box");
        itemDateBox.textContent = "Start: ";

        const itemDate = document.createElement("span");
        itemDate.classList.add("ag-courses-item_date");
        itemDate.textContent = bloodType.unit;

        itemDateBox.appendChild(itemDate);

        itemLink.appendChild(itemBg);
        itemLink.appendChild(itemTitle);
        itemLink.appendChild(itemDateBox);

        const coursesItem = document.createElement("div");
        coursesItem.classList.add("ag-courses_item");
        coursesItem.appendChild(itemLink);

        const coursesBox = document.createElement("div");
        coursesBox.classList.add("ag-courses_box");
        coursesBox.appendChild(coursesItem);

        const formatContainer = document.createElement("div");
        formatContainer.classList.add("ag-format-container");
        formatContainer.appendChild(coursesBox);

        container.appendChild(formatContainer);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
{% endblock content %}
```

**original card code**
[code](https://codepen.io/wikyware-net/pen/dyKPRxQ)

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding css property

```
display: flex;
```

in **ag-format-container** class